# How to sample random values in an ST monad?

Tags: haskell, random, monad-transformers

If I have a random value generator in the [`RVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.0/docs/Data-Random.html#t:RVar) monad

```
ranfu :: RVar Bool
```

and a higher-order  function that does some kind of traversal in (e.g.) the `ST` monad

```
stTrav :: PrimMonad m => (Int -> m b) -> m [b]
```

then how could I use `ranfu` in the loop of this traversal? Do I need to channel the state of the `RVar` through an `STRef`, or is there a better way?

Comment: Mmm, what "better way" are you thinking of? There's nothing inherently random in `ST` itself as far as I'm concerned. AFAIK there are three ways to "unpack" an `RVal` and those are `runRVar`, `sampleRVar` and `sampleState`. If your `ST` can somehow provide `MonadRandom` instance, you can use the 2nd one.

Comment: I would not expect this to be legal.  `ST` is supposed to be deterministic after you run it; randomness violates that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman of course you'd first need to introduce a seed somehow, after that it's perfectly deterministic.

Comment: I'd try to equip [`PromptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadPrompt-1.0.0.5/docs/Control-Monad-Prompt.html#t:PromptT) and [`RVarT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rvar-0.2.0.3/docs/Data-RVar.html#t:RVarT) with [`MFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) and [`PrimMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Primitive.html) instances (there are no obvious obstacles), then `hoist lift ranfu` into `RVarT ST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the `RandomSource` instance for `ST` in [`Data.Random.Source.MWC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-source-0.3.0.6/docs/Data-Random-Source-MWC.html):

```
import Data.Random.Source.MWC

sample :: [Bool]
sample = runST $ do
  g <- create
  stTrav (\i -> runRVar ranfu g)
```